Write registry value into textfile using powershell
I'm tring to export the open notebook fielpaths from OneNote into a text file.
But no matter what I try, I can't get it to work.
Am I missing something obvious here? There are definitly values in this registry path.
$registryPath = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OneNote\OpenNotebooks"
$filePath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
$outFile = Join-Path -Path $filePath -ChildPath "OneNotePaths.txt"

Get-ChildItem -Path $registryPath | ForEach-Object {
  $notebookPath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath).Path
  Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value $notebookPath
}

Edit: the script somehow does not enter the ForeEach loop as if there ar no items found in the Path.

please, define how it is not working.


Edit: the script somehow does not enter the ForeEach loop as if there ar no items found in the Path.

That's correct - because there are no child items under the OpenNoteBooks key - the listed notebooks are stored in values attached to the key itself. To get those values, use Get-ItemProperty (or Get-ItemPropertyValue):
$openBooksKey = Get-Item $registryPath
$openBooksKey.GetValueNames() |ForEach-Object {
  $openBooksKey |Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name $_ |Add-Content -Path $outFile
}


Just to be curious:  In what does your answer conceptually differ from mine, except that you use a slightly more circuitous syntactical approach?

@Halfix Aside from the brief explanation of why the current approach doesn't work: mostly stylistically. I don't find code riddled with aliases particularly useful for educational purposes - verbose command names are much easier to google :)

I don't use the PS registry provider so I never thought how tricky enumerating the values of registry-entries could be.
This is how it works for your case. I use aliases to make the pipeline a little bit easier to read. You may retranslate them if you prefer the full statements:
gi $registryPath | %{ ac $outfile ( gpv $registryPath $_.Property ) }

